# ASP.Net MVC3 - Custom data annotation to force to upper-case

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, uppercase

I'd like to create a custom data annotation that will force the data entered to be upper-cased. If the user types something in lower-case, it should be automatically (and silently) converted to upper-case. This is **not** a validation issue.

I'd like something like this:

```
public class Address {
    public string Address {get; set;}
    public string City {get; set;}

    [ForceUpperCase]
    public string State{get; set;}

}
```

For example, when using @HTML.EditorFor(x => x.State) I'd like the HTML that's created to take care of all of this for me - I don't want to have to write jQuery calls to change the data or force in a particular class name.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I don't see a way of doing this with an attribute. But you can always use a backing field for your property, like so:

```
public class Address {
    private string _state;

    public string Address {get; set;}
    public string City {get; set;}

    public string State
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set { _state = value.ToUpper(); }
    }
}
```

Sure, it is much uglier, but it works.

Comment: Yes, it is a little uglier, but it also missed the desire to have the conversion to upper-case happen within the browser, and not just during the postback. Thanks, though...

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question, didn't see you wanted something client-side.

Answer (score 0):

My line of code in the view is:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BldgNameAbbv, new {onkeyup="InputToUpper(this);"})
```

The associated script is:

```
<script>
function InputToUpper(obj)
{
    if (obj.value!="")
    {
    obj.value = obj.value.toUpperCase();
    }
}
</script>
```

This worked for me. And using TextBoxFor, instead of EditorFor, was essential.

For EditorFor:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @onkeyup = "InputToUpper(this);" } })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also force upper case in CSS with text-transform property. [(See this)](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp)

#### CSS:

```
.upperCase 
{
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
}
```

**!important** is not mandatory.

---

#### View (Razor):

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Property, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "upperCase" } })
```

---

if you use traditional html, you just need to add the html attribute class="upperCase" on your input.

#### Html:

```
<input type="text" class="upperCase"/>
```

---

See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/ahLw7uq2/

Comment: at the backend it will still be in the original case